# Problems with Random Image Script in JS

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get the following script to replace the default images by a random image every time the page refreshes. I keep getting a boxID is null error. Why is boxID null?

```
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function randomThumbs(){
    var unalafois=1;
    for (unalafois=1; unalafois<9; unalafois++){
    boxID=document.getElementById("'unalafois'")
    var duh= Math.ceil(Math.random()*8);
    boxID.src="thumbs/'+duh+'.jpg";
    }}
    </script>
```

Here is the HTML code:

```
<body onload="randomThumbs()">
<table>
    <tr>
      <td><img id="1" src="thumbs/1.jpg" /></td>
      <td><img id="2" src="thumbs/2.jpg" /></td>
      <td><img id="3" src="thumbs/3.jpg" /></td>
      <td><img id="4" src="thumbs/4.jpg" /></td>
      <td><img id="5" src="thumbs/5.jpg" /></td>
      <td><img id="6" src="thumbs/6.jpg" /></td>
      <td><img id="7" src="thumbs/7.jpg" /></td>
      <td><img id="8" src="thumbs/8.jpg" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ID for a HTMLElement cannot start with a number.
Change the ID's to something like img-n, where n is a number.

```
<body onload="randomThumbs()">
<table>
        <tr>
            <td><img id="img-1" src="thumbs/1.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img id="img-2" src="thumbs/2.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img id="img-3" src="thumbs/3.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img id="img-4" src="thumbs/4.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img id="img-5" src="thumbs/5.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img id="img-6" src="thumbs/6.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img id="img-7" src="thumbs/7.jpg" /></td>
            <td><img id="img-8" src="thumbs/8.jpg" /></td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

Then change your script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    function randomThumbs(){
        var unalafois=1;
        for (unalafois=1; unalafois<9; unalafois++){
          //Use var before boxID, just a best practice
            var boxID = document.getElementById("img-" + unalafois)
            var duh= Math.ceil(Math.random()*8);
            boxID.src="thumbs/" + duh + ".jpg";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: This didn't completely solve the problem, but it helped a lot; cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes if you want to use `unalafois` as a variable:

`boxID=document.getElementById(unalafois)`

And don't use IDs starting with numbers, it's illegal if you want to conform to [HTML Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! The problem was missing quotes around the 1 on line 3. Here is the final script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function randomThumbs(){
var onecell="1";
for (onecell=1; onecell<9; onecell++){
var picnum=Math.ceil(Math.random()*9);
document.getElementById("img" +onecell).setAttribute("src","thumbs/"+picnum+".jpg");
}}
</script>
```